# Regular expression in python that has optional text in the string

Tags: python, regex

I have three possible forms that will go through a regular expression, and I'd like to match them all.

```
text1
text1 text2
text1 text2 ;text3
```

I've got so far `(.*?)(?:\s)(.*)` working for `'text1 text2'`, but I able to handle all three cases if the semicolon is present.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your desired matching text is not really text1, text2, and text3, right?  Can you give more explanation on the text forms to match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, it would also put 'text1', 'text2', and 'text3' into the correct groups:

```
^(.+?)(?:\s(.*?)(?:\s;(.*))?)?$
```

See it working: http://www.rubular.com/r/IyPyF3wXLx

Here is an explanation:

```
^                # start of string
(.+?)            # put text1 in group 1
(?:              # start an optional non-capturing group
  \s(.*?)        # space followed by text2, put text2 in group 2
  (?:            # start an optional non-capturing group
    \s;(.*)      # space and semicolon, followed by text3, put text3 in group 3
  )?             # end of optional non-capturing group
)?               # end of optional non-capturing group
$                # end of string
```

The optional groups in the middle allow your regex to match text2 and text3 if they are present, but still match if they are not.